# Excel VBA: VBA Function Called as Formula Runs Differently?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Here is the macro that I have

```
Option Explicit

Function AutoFormula(blocks As Range, target As Range)
    Dim blockedArr() As String
    Dim cellValue As String
    Dim ret As String
    Dim i As Integer

    'sprawdzenie zakresu
    If (blocks.Cells.Count > 1) Then
        AutoFormula = "Tylko 1 komórka jako parametr!"
        Exit Function
    End If

     'wczytanie komorki
    cellValue = blocks.Cells(1, 1).Value

    'split
    blockedArr = Split(cellValue, ",")

    ret = "=WYSZUKAJ.PIONOWO(E7;$E$2:$G$5;3;FAŁSZ)"

    For i = LBound(blockedArr, 1) To UBound(blockedArr, 1)
        ret = ret + "+SUMA.JEŻELI(A7:A1000;" + blockedArr(i) + ";G7:G1000)"
    Next i

    target.Cells(1, 1).FormulaLocal = ret

    AutoFormula = 1
End Function

Sub auto()
    Call AutoFormula(Worksheets("reorganizacja").Range("D7"), Worksheets("reorganizacja").Range("G7"))
End Sub
```

When I run it using the auto() sub it works fine and produces a desired result. However, if I call it as a formula in excell cell like `=AutoFormula(D7;G7)` it doesn't work. In the Excell cell I get the #ARG error. When I debug the macro it goes properly until `target.Cells(1, 1).FormulaLocal = ret` line and when I step over it breaks the function immediately without completing it.
Any ideas?

Comment: Write `debug.print ret` before the error and share the result in the immediate window.

Comment: this is the result:`=WYSZUKAJ.PIONOWO(E7;$E$2:$G$5;3;FAŁSZ)+SUMA.JEŻELI(A7:A1000;135;G7:G1000)`. The formula is ok (as when I run it through sub it works fine). I also tried replacing the problematic line with a simple string `target.Cells(1, 1).FormulaLocal = "john"` and the results are the same so it doesn't seem like an issue with value of 'ret'

Answer (score 5):

A UDF can only return a value to the cell(s) whence it was called - it must not modify the contents or formatting of any cell and must not modify the operating environment of Excel. If you attempt to change anything, the function will terminate immediately and return a `#VALUE` error to the calling cell. 
[Source - Cpearson.com](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/writingfunctionsinvba.aspx)

In your case, you are trying to change the value of a range argument in Excel, e.g. `target` is an argument and through `target.Cells(1, 1).FormulaLocal = ret` you are asking Excel to change it.

---

With other words, imagine that you want to double the value of `A1` through a UDF. A way to achieve it is through this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function DoubleArgument(a As Range) As Double
    a = a * 2
    DoubleArgument = a
End Function

Public Sub TestMe()
    Debug.Print DoubleArgument(Range("A1"))
End Sub
```

However, as mentioned, you cannot change values in Excel through a UDF, thus if you run `=DoubleArgument(A1)` in Excel it would be an error.

---

If you want to simplify the example, eliminating the parameters, try the following:

```
Public Function Put5InA1()
    Range("A1") = 5
End Function

Public Sub TestMe()
    Debug.Print Put5InA1
End Sub
```

`TestMe()` would generate `5` in `A1` and the UDF `=Put5InA1()` would return an error.

Comment: How then can you make a macro that changes a formula of a given cell (without hardcoding the cell in the macro itself)?